# Notification whenever a program connect to internet/outside

Tags: networking, firewall, notification

I always use public WiFi in my college. Hence I thought of setting up a firewall. It was not as easy as I thought. My current set up is that all incoming connections are blocked except ssh. Is there a way by which I can configure Ubuntu to give me notifications whenever a new connection is made/attempted, both IN/OUT?

The idea is that I need to be informed in real time about this, ideally via `notify-send`. Then I should be able to suppress some notifications, which are redundant. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could monitor the output of `netstat`. the flags `-tpan` allow viewing which program uses which port. In theory you could write a simple script that constantly checks number of those connections with  `grep`, and if the number of connections have changed, you could get a notification. Note, that `sshd` won't be shown unless you run that command with sudo, so the script would probably need to be ran with sudo as well. I doubt `notify-send` would allow listing large amount of connections , but you could use `zenity` and it's list dialog.

Another way, though only for incoming connections, is not monitor `who` command. Since you're blocking all connections except ssh, you're probably more concerned with who's loggin in into your machine. You could use `watch -n5 -d who` , where `-n` is the interval for repeating the command in seconds, and `-d` is the flag to high light differences between the previous and current result of the command

Answer (score 0):

You could, but it would be a bad idea: your notify system will be overwhelmed by the constant sniffing/probing from the Internet and your outgoing connections …

If you still want to move ahead, I would:

First move the [iptables log to it's own file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348439/iptables-log-file-and-how-change-it)

and then open a terminal window and do a:

```
tail --follow /var/log/iptables.log
```

and then you'll understand why having a notify isn't really practical …