# Redirect iptables logging to another logfile

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, log, rsyslog

I have followed the recipe by @Gilles in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348439/iptables-log-file-and-how-change-it). I succeeded, but the problem is that the iptables logging now goes into 3 log files, syslog, kern.log and iptables.log.

Ideally, I want the iptables logging go only into one file, iptables.log.

Comment: Thanks to all. I found the answer. It is necessary to prepend the name of the conf file with a number to assure that it is loaded before all the other rules. In this case, it should be '10-my_iptables.conf'.

Comment: in order to help other folks experiencing the same issue, can you add an answer to your own question, with more detail on how you fixed it? It's fine to mark your own answer as correct, if it fixes the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that rsyslog was loading the **50-default.conf** preferences before the custom preferences set in **my_iptables.conf**.

The solution was to add a number prefix to the conf filename, one that was lower than 50. So I renamed it to **10-my_iptables.conf**.

File **/etc/rsyslog.d/10-my_iptables.conf**

```
# Log kernel generated iptables log messages to file
:msg,contains,"[ipT" /var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```

iptables logging prefix:

```
... -j LOG --log-prefix "[ipT4] ...
```

ip6tables logging prefix:

```
... -j LOG --log-prefix "[ipT6] ...
```

Then I restarted **rsyslog**:

```
# sudo service rsyslog restart
```

This had the desired effect -- all iptables logging was now directed to '/var/log/iptables.log'.