# Ubuntu 22.04 rsyslog "& stop" not stopping?

Tags: iptables, log

I want to log iptables messages in a separate log file, and not in `/var/log/syslog`.

I understand if you want to log something exclusively [to a separate file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789516/redirect-iptables-logging-to-another-logfile), you make sure the syslog rules you want are read before the defaults, and put `& stop` at the end to prevent that rule being read in again (and displayed in syslog). The [order of config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253381/what-order-does-rsyslog-process-configuration-files-in-etc-rsyslog-d) in `/etc/rsyslog.d` is alphabetical.

I've named my config `10-iptables.conf` so it should come before `50-default.conf`. It contains:

```
:msg,contains,"[BLOCKED]" /var/log/iptables.log
& stop
```

My iptables logging rule looks like this:

`-j LOG --log-prefix "[BLOCKED]" -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10`

My `/etc/syslogd/50-default.conf` looks like this (the Ubuntu default config):

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err
*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*
```

However, I see iptables messages in both syslog and my separate file.

It seems like the `& stop` option isn't working, so perhaps my understanding is incorrect. Does anyone know how I can stop putting these messages into `/var/log/syslog`?